# Using Laravel 4 models in custom classes / subsystems without class dependency

Tags: php, xml, parsing, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a parser system that will parse loads of different XML/JSON feeds upon request/cronjob.
I use Laravel 4.

**The purpose of the thread is to use IoC in my context, and not hardcoded Model names in custom-class methods**

Providing an example of parser for Soccer Player with XML structure like:

```
<players category="Midfielders">
   <player id="777">
      <name>Caio Augusto Paim do Santos</name>
   <statistic>
      <club name="Camaçari" id="7191" league="Baiano 2" league_id="1136" season="2013" minutes="" appearences="" lineups="" substitute_in="" substitute_out="" substitutes_on_bench="" goals="" yellowcards="" yellowred="" redcards=""/>
```

I've created an additional directory in my /app folder called /parsers These are custom classes, they all extend or implement custom abstracts/interfaces in the same folder and basically are responsible for receiving path to XML/JSON file and returning a well-structured PHP arrays.

They are added in composer.json in autoload as: `"app/parsers"`

Screenshot of file structure attached[image]

All is good and the code/classes are testable and not dependent on another classes, but here's the problem.

Checkout the XML example, there's thing like:
`<club id="XXX" league_id="YYY" />`
 this is feed club id and feed league id, but I have my own IDs in database referenced to feed IDs.

Like on this screenshot:

[image]

So the logic says: Go to database, check if there's id in league league table with feed_id provided from XML file.
If yes, get it, if not, create a new league and get the id for future references.

This requires me to use Model in my parser classes, now I know you can use IoC and inject models into Controllers, but I'm not sure I can do the same with my parser classes...

So doing something like this in the middle of my parser class:

```
// Try to get league and season ids from database if they already exists, if not, insert
$leagueId = DB::select('SELECT id FROM league WHERE feed_id=?', array($data['league_id']));
```

or

```
$league = new LeagueModel();
```

Is pretty much incorrect.

Now just to clarify the way it all works, my parsers are getting called in Laravel Command classes like this:

```
/**
* Execute the console command.
*
* @return void
*/
public function fire()
{
    $this->setParser();
    $this->setStorage();
    $this->parser->parseFile($file);
}
```

And Laravel Command classes are getting called in my Controllers like:

```
$stamps = $this->getStamp();
Artisan::call('command:getSoccerPlayer',array('stamps' => $stamps, 'parser_id' => Request::segment(2)));
```

The Controller itself is called via URI:
`/jobs/soccer_player/parse?type=soccer&directory=players`

**What do you suggest or how would you overcome this issue to avoid dependencies and still use Models for interactions with the database in this context? **

P.S Please don't pay attention that the whole parse logic on my screenshot is in the same method "parse" now, I will break it into pieces once I see the full picture of how I want it to work/look.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What's your purpose in avoiding dependencies? Do you mean avoiding using dependency injection to add a Model into your class? Have you checked out the use of an interfaced repository ("repository pattern")?

Comment: My purpose is to use IoC and not hardcoded model names/queries inside of a parsing method. I just can't figure out how. Laravel's community is pretty low and never answering. :(

Answer (score 1):

you can still call your namespaced models

```
use App\Models\League; 

class SoccerPlayerParser extends AbstractParser{
    //...

    public function parse()
    {
       //...
        $league = App\Models\League::find($data['league_id']);
       //...
    }

    //....
}
```

Comment: Not really. If I give namespace to my model, it loses the namespace provided by Laravel by default, thus I don't have an access to DB facade anymore :-/

Comment: Please can you explain more as to how it loses its facade
Namespacing is basically telling the SoccerPlayerParser class where to find the league class

Comment: After I declare it a namespace like: `namespace App\Models;
class League extends Eloquent {` 
Without it, SoccerPlayerParser doesn't know anything about App\Models namespace :/

Comment: after you add the namespace can't you just add 'use DB'? and whats in your composer.json?

Comment: "Not really. If I give namespace to my model, it loses the namespace provided by Laravel by default, thus I don't have an access to DB facade anymore :-/"

You still do. Once you apply a namespace, it removes the defined class from the global class namespace. If you'd like to use a class from the global namespace (i.e. DB), just add `use DB;` after your namespace declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions here, but am not 100% sure how to integrate it in your project.

The first is to store the name of the model class to use in a config file and intantiate the model via `new $class` where $class is a value retrieved via `Config::get` or similar. This solution is very common in packages, and even Laravel itself uses it (see the model setting in app/config/auth.php).

The other is to not instantiate the model, but instead create an interface for it and then dependency-inject it into your command. You can easily auto-inject stuff into your commands by using `Artisan::resolve('MyNamespace\MyCommand')` instead of `Artisan::add(new MyCommand)`, and then inject via type hinting as you do via controllers. http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#practical-usage

Once you've set up the interface as an argument to the command's constructor, you can use `App::bind('MyInterface', 'MyModel')` to tell Laravel which class to inject, and this can be swapped at any point.